# Marangoni effect and surface tension gradients in binary liquid

Tags: thermodynamics, surface-tension, stability

I have a question regarding the understanding of the Marangoni effect. A simple visualization is the deposition of a drop of soap (some surfactant-laden solution) into pure water. Because the soap drop has smaller surface tension, the cohesive forces of the pure water molecules will lead to the retraction, or moving away of those molecules, and the soapy drop area will increase. My question is now: I have learned that surface tension is always associated with a reduction of contact area. So if i imagine this experiment as two concentric circles (radius Rw and Rs, respectively for pure water region and soap drop radius), then shouldnt the system evolve in such a way as to minimize the contact area between pure water molecules and soapy water molecules, leading to a reduction of Rs?

Any help in understanding that would be appreciated!!

A follow up question would be: Imagine now the same system, but in 3D and no gravity; a spherical drop of solution of lower surface tension is inserted into a larger spherical drop of higher surface tension. How will the Marangoni effect then take place?

Thanks in advance,

M.